# Can't connect two Azure Virtual Machines - permission denied (public key)

Tags: azure, permissions, virtual-machine, virtual

I am trying to connect two Microsoft Azure virtual machines. Both are on the same virtual network. When I try to connect with ssh, the terminal returns Permission denied(publickey). Thoughts on why I am receiving this error? I tried checking my network inbound/outbound port rules and there is no firewall on the virtual network.

So my problem is not with connecting between my machine and the VMs, that works fine. I am not able to connect using ssh between two VM's.

Comment: Welcome. Please re-read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and then edit you question to display the exact error messages. In your research, did you search existing posts on stackoverflow; such as [Cannot connect to Azure Ubuntu VM - Public Key Denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22218282/), or [Azure acs ssh login keeping failing with “permission denied (public key)”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36380158/)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot connect to Azure Ubuntu VM - Public Key Denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22218282/cannot-connect-to-azure-ubuntu-vm-public-key-denied)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this description:

> When you use an SSH client to connect to your Linux VM (which has the
>   public key), the remote VM tests the client to make sure it possesses
>   the private key. If the client has the private key, it's granted
>   access to the VM.

It seems the problem happens to your public key. When you create the Azure VM with a public key, you should make sure that the public key is also in your home directory, for example, ~/.ssh/. It means both your local machine and the VM stored the public key. Then you can use the public key to ssh your Azure VM with the permission accept from your local machine. You can see the steps [How to create the VM with a public key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/ssh-from-windows#provide-an-ssh-public-key-when-deploying-a-vm).

Comment: Thank you for the response. Okay, I followed those steps and my problem still occurs when trying to connect two VM's using ssh, not between my machine and the VM's.

Comment: If it happens to all your VMs or just some? And what the steps that you create the VM with the public key?

Comment: Yes, it happens when I try to connect between two VM's and it is all of them. I generated a public key on my machine and used it for setup in Microsoft Azure. In debugging the connection between two VM's, it shows that a connection is made, but that it is unable to authenticate the private key and says "no more authentication methods to try. permission denied"

Comment: The two VMs with the same public key cannot ssh to each other? Then you can try to reset the public key for the VM to check if the key is wrong.